# Trying to share .ism (Azure Media Player) video to facebook

Tags: html, facebook, azure

i just would like to ask if this is posible? currently doing some facebook integration with my current site and tried including a video URL on the open graph meta tag for sharing/posting and gives me an error. I am wondering if there is a way of doing this. Thanks!

```
 <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://test.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/e58e3f83-0904-4886-836e-ac28303831fe/INTRO VID.ism">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://test.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/e58e3f83-0904-4886-836e-ac28303831fe/INTRO VID.ism">
```

Comment: Flash (swf) or mp4 are the formats you can embed.

Comment: i have tried putting ".mp4" as an extension instead of the ".ism/manifest", still does not work :(

Comment: _Is_ it an mp4 video file, or did you just change the extension …?

Comment: Hi CBroe, videos are being upload which can be any of these type. (flv, mxf, gxf, ts, ps, 3gp, 3gpp, mpg, wmv, asf, avi, mp4, m4a, m4v, isma, ismv, dvr-ms, mkv, wav, mov). The ".ism" extension is a published (by Azure Media Services) version of those videos as streaming files.

Comment: It has to be either swf or mp4.

Comment: Yes i figured that out too. Though I am not sure if Azure Media Services can publish videos as MP4, not as ISM.